# React Native - CSS :last-child without a border?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

In React Native, I have a static array of books that I map over and output in stacked rows like this:

```
return books.map((book, i) => {
  return(
    <View style={styles.book} key={i}>
      <Text style={styles.book}>{book.title}</Text>
    </View>
  );
});
```

I also have a bottom border on each book via `styles.book`:

```
book: {
  borderBottomWidth: 1,
  borderBottomColor: '#000000'
}
```

I need the last book in the list to NOT have a bottom border, so I'll need to apply `borderBottomWidth: 0` to it I think? In React Native, how can I get the last book in the list to not have that bottom border? (In normal css we'd use last-child)

Comment: I dont know react but bottom does not come at the end? like borderWidthBottom?

Comment: books[books.length - 1] is last one in javascript

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You could achieve this using some logic:

```
return books.map((book, i) => {
  return(
    <View style={ (i === books.length - 1) ? styles.noBorderBook : styles.book} key={i}>
      <Text style={(i === books.length - 1) ? styles.noBorderBook : styles.book}>{book.title}</Text>
    </View>
  );
});
```

What this does is check if `i`, the iterator, is equal to the books array's `length - 1`.

Comment: Thank you, works great, just added the - 1 to match the last key!

Answer (score 16):

You can try [extended-stylesheet](https://github.com/vitalets/react-native-extended-stylesheet#pseudo-classes-nth-child) that supports `:last-child`:

```
import EStyleSheet from 'react-native-extended-stylesheet';

const styles = EStyleSheet.create({
  book: {
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    borderBottomColor: '#000000'
  },
  'book:last-child': {
    borderBottomWidth: 0
  }
});

return books.map((book, i) => {
  const style = EStyleSheet.child(styles, 'book', i, book.length);
  return(
    <View style={style} key={i}>
      <Text style={style}>{book.title}</Text>
    </View>
  );
});
```