# React-native CSS 'last-child' property

Tags: css, react-native, css-selectors

Here is my code:

```
<ListView style={styles.mainContent}
    ref={(scrollView) => { _scrollView = scrollView; }}
    dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
    renderRow={this.renderRow.bind(this)}
/>
```

and the styling of that code:

```
mainContent: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
    borderBottomColor: '#CCCCCC',
    paddingLeft: 15,
    paddingRight: 15
},
```

Now, for every 'ListView' there is a border, and on the last section, I want that border to be removed or overwritten. But in react-native it's not possible to use :last-child.

I have tried using the answers given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37245481/react-native-css-last-child-without-a-border), but I was unable to get a result. (I'm still new to React(-native))

Anyone have an idea?

Comment: Did you try the ESS: https://github.com/vitalets/react-native-extended-stylesheet#pseudo-classes-nth-child ?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the link I included.

Comment: Sorry, I attach the link that I guess that is your solution on the link you included. If that doesn't works for you , I don't know how to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using ListView, try using ScrollView and iterate over the elements you want to show like the following example (assuming the variable DataSource is the array of values you want to render)

```
render() {
  const innerElems = DataSource.map((e, i) => {
    if (i === DataSource.length - 1) {
      // check if it's last elem, if so the no border style that you want
      return <View style={styles.noBottomBorder}> ... </View>
    } 
    return <View style={styles.withBottomBorder}> ... </View>
  });
  return (
    <ScrollView style={styles.mainContent}>
      {innerElems}
    </ScrollView>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `ListView`, just for example pass to the `renderRow` property the length of your `DataSource` and check for it in the function you passed, for example like this:

`const lastRow = DataSource.length - 1;`

...

`renderRow={this.renderRow.bind(this, lastRow)}`

and then in the `renderRow` you can get the current rows ID, like:

```
renderRow(rowData, sectionID, rowID, lastRow) {
 // the rowID is what you are looking for, so check if it is the last one, and do some styling to remove the unwanted border
}
```